# SQLAlchemy execute() return not only the value of the cell in database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I execute the following code in my "app.py" and it works, while `session.execute` return not only the value of the cell but also characters like `()` and `,`.

`var = db.session.execute(text(f"SELECT city FROM world WHERE country = Germany")).fetchone()`

without using `fetchone()`, the code showed me the memory address.

The output is `('Berlin',)`, How can I get only `Berlin`?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an exact command instead of `fetchone()` or `fetchall()` to provide the pure cell value `Berlin`.

However, with Regex I turn the `('Berlin',)` to `Berlin` as bellow:

```
var = "('Berlin',)"
var = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z\s]", var)
var = ''.join(var)
print(var)
```

I provide a white-space as maybe some cities names has two part with a space.

Comment: The output isn't the string "('Berlin',)".  The output of fetchone() is a tuple, since the SQL could request more than one field.

Comment: "an exact command instead of fetchone() or fetchall() to provide the pure cell value Berlin" - That would be `.scalar()`

Comment: Dear @GordThompson, you are right, this is the true answer

Answer (score 0):

Since the SQL could be returning multiple fields, fetchone is returning the results as a tuple.  For example, if you changed your select to 'SELECT city, country...', you would have gotten back ('Berlin', 'Germany').

To extract just 'Berlin' use var[0].